# Proof Correction: if $f = f'$, then $f = e^x$

Tags: real-analysis

My textbook states that if $f = f'$, then $f = ce^x$. I can't see the flaw in my proof however (which is totally different from the textbook's).

**Proof**

$f$ keeps the same sign. Suppose otherwise, $f$ changes sign at some point. Then $f$ goes from positively increasing or negatively decreasing (since $f$ is increasing/ decreasing if and only if $f$ is positive/ negative) to a discontinuous positive/ negative point, contradicting continuity of $f$.

Since $f'$ keeps the same sign, $f$ is one-one, and $f^{-1}$ is a function.

Thus $(f^{-1})' = \cfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))} = \cfrac{1}{x}$

It follows that $$ f^{-1} = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \ dt = \log x $$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Hence $f = e^x$.

[image]

Comment: Why is the lower limit $1?$

Comment: And note that changing the lower limit introduces a constant term.

Comment: Do it as an antiderivative and you will see $f^{-1}=\log x + C$.

Comment: PLUS A CONSTANT!!!!!!  PLUS A CONSTANT!!!!!!!  $f^{-1}$'$ = \frac 1x $ so $f^{-1} = \logx$   PLUS A CONSTANT!!!!!

Comment: Also, you should say why $f(x) \neq 0$.  (If $f'(x)=0$, then by continuity $f \equiv 0$.)

Comment: f(x) can equal 0. In the case, f(x) = ce$^x$ with c = 0.

Answer (score 3):

Nice proof, but, why does the integral need to be 1 at the lower limit:

$$f^{-1} = \int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln x + \textrm{const.}$$

$$ f = \textrm{const.} \exp x$$